# Model does not contain a definition for List and no extension method List accepting a first argument of type system.linq.IQueryable) could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a method with a return type of a custom model but am receiving the "does not contain" error. The call is as follows, it is coming from a public actionresult method.

```
if (panDetails.FirstOrDefault().PanelType == 1)
{
    var result3 = BranchLoad(panID);
}
```

and the method is as follows.

```
public vmBPanel BranchLoad(int? panID)
{

    vmBPanel ccts = (from pc in db.PH_PanelCircuits.Where(x => x.PanelID == panID)
                from ph in db.PH_PanelBPPhase.Where(x => x.cct == pc.cct)
                from pj in db.PH_POCPanJoin.Where(x => x.PanCctID == pc.PanCctID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from poc in db.tblPowerPOCs.Where(r => r.POCID == pj.POCID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new vmBPanel
                {
                    PanCctID = pc.PanCctID,
                    PanelID = pc.PanelID,
                    cct = pc.cct,
                    Phase = ph.phase,
                    POCID = (pj == null) ? (int?)null : pj.POCID,
                    DateUpdated = (pj == null) ? (DateTime?)null : pj.DateUpdated,
                    Assigned = (poc == null) ? string.Empty : poc.EntityCode + '-' + poc.FPOC

                }).List();


    return ccts;
}
```

The error is:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'List' and no extension method 'List' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Its `.ToList()` not `.List()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `List()` on the end of the query, this should be `ToList()`.